# Bash output to file no new line

Tags: linux, bash

I am stuck at the moment and need some help please. I am running the following command:

```
echo  $(ps aux |sort -nrk 3,3 | head -n 10) > text.txt
```

And the output I am getting is all in one big block

```
student 2066 16.5 7.4 1609208 299500 ? Ssl 07:31 12:16 compiz student 2803 13.3 8.3 2261736 339840 ? Sl 07:33 9:40 /usr/lib/firefox/plugin-container -greomni /usr/lib/firefox/omni.ja -appomni /usr/lib/firefox/browser/omni.ja -appdir /usr/lib/firefox/browser 2720 true tab student 2720 6.5 9.1 2435552 370424 ? Sl 07:33 4:47 /usr/lib/firefox/firefox root 884 5.3 2.8 365268 116248 tty7 Ssl+ 07:31 4:02 /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg -core :0 -seat seat0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch student 2700 0.6 1.1 801556 46540 ? Sl 07:33 0:26 /usr/bin/gedit --gapplication-service student 2023 0.1 3.4 1312876 138932 ? Sl 07:31 0:05 /usr/bin/gnome-software --gapplication-service student 2017 0.1 1.3 832524 55068 ? Sl 07:31 0:04 nautilus -n student 1337 0.1 0.0 116164 2084 ? Sl 07:31 0:07 /usr/bin/VBoxClient --draganddrop whoopsie 592 0.0 0.3 373952 12352 ? Ssl 07:30 0:00 /usr/bin/whoopsie -f USER PID %CPU %MEM VSZ RSS TTY STAT START TIME COMMAND
```

I am wondering if there is away of having that output line by line.

```
student 2066 16.5 7.4 1609208 299500 ? Ssl 07:31 12:16 compiz 
student 2803 13.3 8.3 2261736 339840 ? Sl 07:33 9:40 /usr/lib/firefox/plugin-container -greomni /usr/lib/firefox/omni.ja -appomni /usr/lib/firefox/browser/omni.ja -appdir /usr/lib/firefox/browser 2720 true tab 
student 2720 6.5 9.1 2435552 370424 ? Sl 07:33 4:47 /usr/lib/firefox/firefox root 884 5.3 2.8 365268 116248 tty7 Ssl+ 07:31 4:02 /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg -core :0 -seat seat0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch student 2700 0.6 1.1 801556 46540 ? Sl 07:33 0:26 /usr/bin/gedit --gapplication-service student 2023 0.1 3.4 1312876 138932 ? Sl 07:31 0:05 /usr/bin/gnome-software --gapplication-service student 2017 0.1 1.3 832524 55068 ? Sl 07:31 0:04 nautilus -n 
student 1337 0.1 0.0 116164 2084 ? Sl 07:31 0:07 /usr/bin/VBoxClient --draganddrop whoopsie 592 0.0 0.3 373952 12352 ? Ssl 07:30 0:00 /usr/bin/whoopsie -f USER PID %CPU %MEM VSZ RSS TTY STAT START TIME COMMAND
```

I am looking to do it in BASH only as that is what I am teaching myself at the moment and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: just `ps aux |sort -nrk 3,3 | head -n 10 > text.txt`

Comment: @Matthew Swart I really wonder why do you use echo $(some command) instead of using them directly/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
somecmd $(...)
```

This is the most common mistake to make in a Bash / POSIX shell script, not quoting the expansion of a variable or a command substitution.

The problem is the same as here:

```
var="foo     bar"             # couple of spaces
echo $var
```

Since `$var` is not quoted, it's split on whitespace, and the resulting words are given as separate arguments to `echo`. And `echo` prints all its  arguments separated by single spaces. In your example, the newlines coming from the command substitution are similarly used to split the input.

Compare with

```
echo "$var"
```

and see: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting and the first two items in http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls

---

And of course, what the command substitution `$(...)` does, is take the output of a command and put it on the command line of another command. Which is pretty much the opposite of what `echo` does, taking input from the command line and printing it to standard output. So you could just remove both and redirect the output of your `ps ...` command directly.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you have to `echo` the command-substitution(`$(..)`) output, when you can just do,

```
ps aux |sort -nrk 3,3 | head -n 10 > text.txt
```

Comment: Just the way I have learned over the past week from all the stuff I have read on-line.